# Trocar label do inputfile quando já tiver um arquivo selecionado Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Tenho o seguinte input file que faz o upload de uma imagem e transforma em base64:

```
            <div class="image-upload">
              <img class="fotoAnimal" [src]="imageSrc" style="max-width:300px;max-height:300px"/>
              <label for="upload" class="file-upload__label">Procurar foto</label>
              <input  id="upload" class="file-upload__input" name="imageUrl" type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="handleInputChange($event)" />
            </div>
```

Minha função que faz o upload:

```
  handleInputChange(e) {
    var file = e.dataTransfer ? e.dataTransfer.files[0] : e.target.files[0];
    var pattern = /image-*/;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    if (!file.type.match(pattern)) {
      alert('Formato inválido, permitido apenas jpeg e');
      return;
    }
    reader.onload = this._handleReaderLoaded.bind(this);
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
  _handleReaderLoaded(e) {
    let reader = e.target;
    this.imageSrc = reader.result;
    console.log(this.imageSrc)
  }
```

Depois que uma imagem é selecionada, o campo continua "Procurar foto", gostaria de trocar para "Procurar outra foto". Como posso fazer isso no angular?

Comment: Jovem acho que vc  consegue resolver isso só com CSS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma variável que recebe seu target.files .

```
var file = e.target.files;
```

E depois pode manipular seu html com essa variável

```
 <label for="upload">Procurar <span *ngIf="file.length > 0"> outra </span foto</label>
```

Se o tamanho dessa variável for maior que zero quer dizer que já tem arquivo ai vc muda seu label.

Espero ter ajudado Obrigado.